# Unresolved pipe json

Tags: angular, pug

I'm using **Angular v15** with **Pug** template engine, and using this `ng-cli-pug-loader` to render the templates.
I'm doing this within **Webstorm v2021.2.4**.

My problem is that the loader plugin doesn't recognize the Common classes from Angular.

It successfully has access to the variables from the Controller, so the plugin seems to be working as intended, however Angular Common pipes are not recognized.

It appears actually that none of the Angular directives are recognised, and also not in the HTML files.

[image: Screenshot of the Problem]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

OK, so this was something related to Webstorm v2021, after updating to v2022 everything is working perfectly !